# Pandas: astype datetime minutes failing

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using pandas 1.5.2.

I have a column of timestamp stored in a pandas dataframe.

`df['Timestamp'].astype('datetime64[Y]')`

```
0    2017-07-11 09:33:14.819
1    2017-07-11 09:33:14.819
2    2017-07-11 09:33:14.819
3    2017-07-11 09:33:14.819
4    2017-07-11 09:33:14.820
         
5   2017-07-11 16:20:52.463
6   2017-07-11 16:20:52.463
7   2017-07-11 16:20:52.463
8   2017-07-11 16:20:52.464
9   2017-07-11 16:20:54.984
```

I used to be able to convert the timestamp to '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' by `df['Timestamp'].astype('datetime64[m]')`. But now this doesn't work and returns the original column.

```
0    2017-07-11 09:33
1    2017-07-11 09:33
2    2017-07-11 09:33
3    2017-07-11 09:33
4    2017-07-11 09:33
         
5   2017-07-11 16:20
6   2017-07-11 16:20
7   2017-07-11 16:20
8   2017-07-11 16:20
9   2017-07-11 16:20
```

Comment: I think pandas only uses datetime with unit ns, not all the different [units](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#arrays-dtypes-dateunits) of numpy datetime. So if you need a specific *format*, go with `strftime`. If you need to round/floor to a certain precision, go with `floor`, `ceil` or `round`, e.g. `.dt.floor("min")` to have minute precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a format of the column like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': ['2017-07-11 09:33:14.819', '2017-07-11 09:33:14.819']
})
print(df)
"""
                 Timestamp
0  2017-07-11 09:33:14.819
1  2017-07-11 09:33:14.819
"""

df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].astype('datetime64[m]')
print(df)
"""
            Timestamp
0 2017-07-11 09:33:00
1 2017-07-11 09:33:00
"""
```

If you want to remove the second format, you can convert the value to `str` and get only the part you want using `slicing`, as follows:

```py
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].astype(str).str[0:16]
print(df)
"""
          Timestamp
0  2017-07-11 09:33
1  2017-07-11 09:33
"""
```